# Aligning div tags next to each other and centering then

Tags: html, css, alignment

I would like to align 3 divs next to each other and center inside a larger div 
HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="third"></div>
```

What should be in my css?

Comment: you need similar to table view is it ? like this ? [first][second][third]

Comment: what have you tried so far ? display:inline-block, inline-table,table/flex, float , column , , other method ?

Comment: I have tried, in css, using margin:0 auto and  float:left but it ignores the float

Comment: okay, can you drop the css you used here too :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="Cell"  id="first">
                    <p>first</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Cell"  id="second">
                    <p>second</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Cell"  id="third">
                    <p>third</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<style>
    .Row
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
#first{
    width:20%;
}
#second{
    width:60%;
}
#third{
    width:20%;
}
```

Comment: it will create table @CGyrillus

Comment: @GCyrillus try with link
https://jsfiddle.net/7vqop4dq/

Comment: For just a simple navigation bar I think the code is too long

Answer (score 0):

This is what I decided to use

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first" style="margin-left:25%;"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
           width: 100%;
           min-width: 900px;
  }
#first {
           width:100px;
           float:left;
}
#second {
           width:100px;
           float:left;
}
#third {
           width:100px;
           float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you used float :

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#wrapper {
  display: inline-block; /* inline-table will do too */
}
#wrapper div {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 5em;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

with float + table

```css
#wrapper {
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
  }
#wrapper > div {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  min-height:5em;
  border:solid;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

with table and table-cell;

```css
#wrapper {
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
  }
#wrapper > div {
  display:table-cell;
  width:100px;
  height:5em;
  border:solid;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

with flex;

```css
#wrapper {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  margin:auto;
  }
#wrapper > div {  
  width:100px;
  height:5em;
  border:solid;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

and they can be lots of  variation depending of behavior expected last.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!